# Страница не видит кукис

Tags: javascript, cookie

В одной папке лежат 2 страницы. На первой странице в js создаётся кукис в который записываются некие данные(path не указывал). Вторая страница должна получить данные из него, однако этот кукис она не видит. На первой странице никаких проблем с кукисом нет. Что делать?
P.s. проблема может быть связана с тем, что я работаю не на сервере а просто с сохраненными страницами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю ты сам ответил на свой вопрос, например Google Chrome куки не сохраняет, если сайт не на сервере в интернете или на Денвере.